# Вызов subroutine из fortran90 кода в C++, Fortran runtime error: Attempting to allocate already allocated variable

Tags: c++, fortran

Есть следующий код на Fortran:

```
subroutine generate(matrix)

    implicit none

    integer :: i, j, k, ierr
    integer :: m, n, l

    double precision rand

    double precision,  allocatable, dimension(:,:,:) :: matrix

    m=3
    n=4
    l=4
    !rand=1.0


    allocate(matrix(3, 4, 4)) !here need to make the code more flexiible TODO


    do i=1, m
        do j=1, n
            do k=1, l
                call random_number (rand)

                matrix(i,j,k)=rand
            enddo 
        enddo
    enddo


    write(*, *) matrix

    end subroutine generate
```

И вызывающий его код на C++:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern "C"
{
    void generate_(double ***);
}

int main()
{
    double ***matrix;

    generate_((&(&(&matrix)[0])[0])[0]);


    for(int i=1;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int j=1;j<4;j++)
        {
            for(int k=1;k<4;k++)
                cout<<matrix[i][j][k];


         }
    }


    return 0;

}
```

Во время выполнения получаю следующую ошибку:

> Fortran runtime error: Attempting to allocate already allocated variable 'matrix'

Если в коде на фортране использовать выделение памяти с "stat=ierr", получаю "segmentation fault"

```
allocate(matrix(3, 4, 4), stat=ierr)
```

GDB выдаёт:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004009e4 in generate (matrix=...) at matrixGen.f90:32
32  matrix(i,j,k)=rand
```

Comment: Перевёл ваш вопрос на русский. В следующий раз будьте добры самостоятельно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давненько не брал в руки Fortran :)

У вас одна концептуальная ошибка в коде, которая по цепочке порождает прочие, а именно вам надо:

- или освобождать массив в том же месте где и аллоцировали
- или же давать процедуре уже аллоцированный массив

Скорее всего (согласно логике вашей проги) - вам надо аллоцировать массив в C и передавать его Fortran'у, чтобы он заполнял массив уже известного размера.

Иначе получается, что после 1-го вызова сабрутины вы аллоцируете массив и нигде его не освобождаете - прямой путь к утечке памяти.

Comment: GDB output:

    Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
    0x0000000000400b5d in main () at main.cpp:57
    57                                      cout<<matrix[i][j][k];
:(

Comment: Это означает, что вы вышли за пределы аллоцированного (выделенного под ваш массив) размеры памяти

Comment: пропустил через gdb и поставил breakpoint на 57 строке если бы привысил  размер то cout<< бы изполнился хотя-бы один раз.

Сдлел принт из фортрновского кода принтит все правильно o_O

Comment: Чисто интуитивно -- попробуйте передать в фортан просто адрес указателя т.е. на C++ написать `generate_((double ***)&matix);` Конечно, это сработает, только если фортран в вашей программе создает не свою обычную матрицу, а ее модель из векторов указателей